# Why do universities announce interviewees for positions as lates as possible?

Tags: united-states, administration

My (R1) university is hiring a number of upper administration positions. We keep getting these emails about the *dates* of the interview, but the *names* aren't released until 24 h beforehand.

My previous (large) department did something similar for our chair search, although I think the names were released more than 24 h earlier.

Why is so much secrecy necessary?

Comment: Could it be that they are planning the interviews before they decide who to interview?

Comment: @Thomas "Interviews" is a bit misleading. These are more like talk/panel discussions with faculty and students who attend. They're scheduled for like a week from now, and I'm sure the search committee has known who they were interested in for a while.

Answer (score 5):

The people who are interviewing for these positions have existing, usually high level, positions at other universities, and care greatly about not having their current employer know that they are looking for other opportunities, to the extent that this can be helped. So the interviewing institutions do the best they can to keep the shortlist candidates’ identity hidden for as long as practically possible.

Thus, balancing out this need for secrecy with other practical considerations leads to the practice you are describing.

Comment: But what does an extra week of secrecy get someone?

Comment: @AzorAhai what does an extra week of non-secrecy get someone?

Comment: A busy person might make time in their schedule to go hear the candidate for dean talk if they think they're an interesting candidate and would have less ability to do so with only a day's warning.

Comment: Also, then everyone only gets one email instead of five.

Comment: @AzorAhai: This way, if the person had decided to withdraw their application during that week, either because they decided to keep their current job or to take a different one, their candidacy for your position would never have been announced publicly at all.

Comment: @AzorAhai true, secrecy has costs, and a 24h notice does sound pretty short. Perhaps your institution has erred on the side of excessive secrecy, leading to a suboptimal solution of this particular optimization problem. You should let them know if you believe that to be the case. Anyway, my answer explains the general thinking behind this phenomenon: generally speaking, institutions will aim for the maximal level of discretion that they believe to still be reasonable and not conflict with other practical issues like the need to have their faculty be engaged in the hiring process.

Comment: @DanRomik I mean, yeah, I get the general idea. I suppose I was surprised by a one-day notice.

Comment: @AzorAhai think about it game-theoretically: institutions want to make themselves attractive to the best candidates, and, knowing that those candidates care about secrecy, will do their best to provide the maximal level of secrecy, perhaps even at the cost of minor annoyance to their existing faculty. They also know that providing less secrecy than other competing institutions might put them at a competitive disadvantage. This can create a sort of arms race that ends with some places eventually giving only an extremely short announcement window to their faculty like you described.